# Regex: get 2 values from multi-line

Tags: regex

I have a text:

```
Session Information

Specification: msl2_1_rx2_file
Session ID: 2015/11/13-19
Type: Backup
Session Owner: mycompany.com
Status: Completed
Mode: incr
Start Time: 11/13/2015 12:07:33 PM
Queuing: 0:00
Duration: 2:24
GB Written: 596.05
# Media: 2
# Errors: 1
# Warnings: 0
```

I want to get two values by regex: `msl2_1_rx2_file` and `1`(errors count)

But I can only know how to have one value:

```
/Specification: (.+)/m
```

http://www.regexr.com/3c6qn

```
/# Errors:\ (.+)/
```

http://www.regexr.com/3c6qq

How to get this 2 values from one regex?
Thanks!

Comment: If your code is in JavaScript, we could show how to use the regexps we came up with. Please state the language/tool you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Make it global and test for one **or** the other -

```
/Specification: (.+)|# Errors:\ (.+)/gm
```

To extract the values get capture group 1 and 2.

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/jD4oX5/1)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternation and `^` start-of-line anchor:

```
/^(?:Specification:|# Errors:) *(.+)/gm
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJ8fL3/2)

Regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of line (as `/m` enforces `^` to match the beginning of a line)
- `(?:Specification:|# Errors:)` - matches either a `Specification:` or `# Errors:`
- `*` - 0 or more regular spaces
- `(.+)` - all characters up to the end of line

The result you need is inside Group 2:

```
msl2_1_rx2_file
1
```

Answer (score 0):

`/(Specification: (.+))|(# Errors:\ (.+))/g`

http://regexr.com/3c6r6